# VSCode Accessing Local Created Variable in Natvis

Tags: vscode-debugger, natvis

I have the following natvis code for visualizing my q23_t class (part of a larger natvis file) in the debugger.I cannot get natvis to show the value of ibit23 which is a locally defined variable. I get the following error:
*-var-create: unable to create variable object*
I want to know how to declare a local variable and access it for my project. Thanks much.

```
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="q23_t">
    <DisplayString> "A" </DisplayString>
    <Expand>
            <Variable Name="ibit23" InitialValue="11" />
            <Item Name="[local]"> ibit23 </Item>
     </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Comment: `<variable>` can only be used in a `<CustomListItems>`. Your question looks like an XY problem. What do you want to achieve with the variable, what is the problem that you want to solve?

Comment: What i was trying to do is as follows: I have a vector of 16 elements containing 24b variables. I want to visualize it as 48 elements of 8b each. So I was hoping to create 3 variables for each element and make each one a separate item.